# Selective regex replacement with the maven-replacer-plugin

Tags: regex, maven, maven-replacer-plugin

I'd like to use the **maven-replacer-plugin** to rename my javascript import statements in my index.html file.

However I would only like to do this where the path starts with `app`

index.html snippet

```
...
<!-- rename this one to app/something12345.js -->
<script src="app/something.js"></script>

<!-- leave this one as it is -->
<script src="vendor/angular.js"></script>
...
```

In my pom.xml so far I have this configuration for the maven-replacer-plugin

```
 <plugin>
     <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
     <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
     <version>1.5.2</version>
     <executions>
         <execution>
             <phase>prepare-package</phase>
             <goals>
                 <goal>replace</goal>
             </goals>
         </execution>
     </executions>
     <configuration>
         <file>target/${project.build.finalName}/index.html</file>
             <replacements>
                 <replacement>
                     <token>(\.js")</token>
                     <value>12345.js"</value>
                 </replacement>
             </replacements>
     </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

At the moment this will obviously replace all the `.js` matches.

Is there some magic incantation I can put in the `<token>` section to achieve this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I managed to do this using the following

```
<replacement>
    <token>((app/)(.)*)(\.js")</token>
    <value>$112345.js</value>
</replacement>
```

although in my real application I replaced `12345` with the `${buildNumber}` variable, so the syntax was

```
<replacement>
    <token>((app/)(.)*)(\.js")</token>
    <value>$1${buildNumber}.js</value>
</replacement>
```

which I hope might make the solution a bit more understandable